# Concurrent modification exception in saveAll() method of JPArepository (Spring DATA JPA + Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have encountered this problem while saving an entity "employee" having oneToOne/oneToMany/ManyToMany type of relationships.

I am using Spring boot + Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and postgres as db.

please find below classes.

Employee Class--

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "emp_id")
private int emp_id;

@Column(name = "emp_name")
private String emp_name;

@Column(name = "d_o_b")
private Date date_of_birth;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "community_employee_mapping", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "community_id") })
private List<Community> listOfCommunities = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Department dept;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

DepartMent class --

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int dept_id;

@Column(name = "dept_name")
private String departmentName;

@Column(name = "dept_desc")
private String departmentDesc;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dept", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Employee> lemp = new ArrayList<>();
```

Community Class --

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "community")
public class Community {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "com_id")
private int community_id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String community_name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listOfCommunities", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Employee> listOfEmployees = new ArrayList<>();

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
```

Address class --

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private int add_id;

@Column(name = "state")
private String state;

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

@Column(name = "zip_code")
private String zip_code;

@Column(name = "country")
private String country;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Employee emp;
```

and below is my spring boot @test method --

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeRepo erepo;

@Autowired
private CommunityRepo crepo;

@Autowired
private DeptRepo drepo;

@Autowired
private AddressRepo arepo;

@Test
public void contextLoads() {

    int max = 1 * 1000 * 100;

    Date date = new GregorianCalendar(1992, 06, 18).getTime();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int index = 0; index < 50000; index++) {
        Employee emp0 = new Employee();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        Employee emp2 = new Employee();

        emp0.setEmp_name(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10) + " " + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5));
        emp0.setDate_of_birth(DateUtils.addDays(date, MathUtil.nextInt(0, 5000)));

        emp1.setEmp_name(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10) + " " + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5));
        emp1.setDate_of_birth(DateUtils.addDays(date, MathUtil.nextInt(0, 5000)));

        emp2.setEmp_name(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10) + " " + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5));
        emp2.setDate_of_birth(DateUtils.addDays(date, MathUtil.nextInt(0, 5000)));

        Community comm0 = new Community();
        comm0.setCommunity_name(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10) + " " + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));
        comm0.setDescription(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(20));

        Community comm1 = new Community();
        comm1.setCommunity_name(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10) + " " + RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));
        comm1.setDescription(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(20));

        List<Employee> lemp = new ArrayList<>();
        lemp.add(emp0);
        lemp.add(emp1);
        comm0.setListOfEmployees(lemp);

        List<Community> lcomm = new ArrayList<>();
        lcomm.add(comm0);

        emp0.setListOfCommunities(lcomm);
        emp1.setListOfCommunities(lcomm);

        List<Employee> lemp2 = new ArrayList<>();
        lemp2.add(emp2);
        comm1.setListOfEmployees(lemp2);

        List<Community> lcomm2 = new ArrayList<>();
        lcomm2.add(comm1);

        emp2.setListOfCommunities(lcomm2);

        Department dept0 = new Department();
        dept0.setDepartmentDesc(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(25));
        dept0.setDepartmentName(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5));

        Department dept1 = new Department();
        dept1.setDepartmentDesc(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(25));
        dept1.setDepartmentName(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5));

        List<Employee> lempp = new ArrayList<>();
        lempp.add(emp0);
        lempp.add(emp1);
        dept0.setLemp(lemp);

        emp0.setDept(dept0);
        emp1.setDept(dept1);

        List<Employee> lempp2 = new ArrayList<>();
        lempp2.add(emp2);
        dept1.setLemp(lempp2);

        emp2.setDept(dept1);

        Address add0 = new Address(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), String.valueOf(MathUtil.nextInt(999999, 9999999)),
                RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), emp0);
        Address add1 = new Address(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), String.valueOf(MathUtil.nextInt(999999, 9999999)),
                RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), emp1);
        Address add2 = new Address(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), String.valueOf(MathUtil.nextInt(999999, 9999999)),
                RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), emp2);

        emp0.setAddress(add0);
        emp1.setAddress(add1);
        emp2.setAddress(add2);

        // erepo.save(emp0);
        // erepo.save(emp1);
        // erepo.save(emp2);

        List<Employee> saveEmp = new ArrayList<>();
        saveEmp.add(emp0);
        saveEmp.add(emp1);
        saveEmp.add(emp2);

        erepo.saveAll(saveEmp);

    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long elapsedTime = end - start;
    System.out.println("elapsed : " + (elapsedTime) + " mili sec.........");

    System.out.println("done writing to db ======================================================================");

}
```

I am using CascadeType.ALL in every relationship so, persisting only parent entity i.e Employee.

Whole code works perfectly fine when i do below. Problem with this approach is it is slow, as we are opening three sessions at back and closing while we have saveAll(iterable args) method which can do it in single session.

```
// erepo.save(emp0);
// erepo.save(emp1);
// erepo.save(emp2);
```

without writing

```
erepo.saveAll(saveEmp);
```

However, when I write saveAll from erepo it creates an arrayList of all items we pass it as iterable argument. Below is the code snippet from SimpleJPArepository class of spring framework.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

    Assert.notNull(entities, "The given Iterable of entities not be null!");

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

I want to confirm here two things...

1)  As I am not attaching any ID to any entity and letting it to be generated on runtime using @GeneratedValue. While persisting entity hibernate is trying to attach an id with entities and thus, changing its state and causing ConcurrentModificationException.

2)  I can make it work by using CopyOnWriteArrayList, but that will again consume space in heap as it will clone whole object graph and hence performance will deviate for sure.

Is there any way I can persist using saveAll() without any performance hit.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: If `Department.lemp` is one-to-many, how is `Employee.dept` one-to-one?

Comment: One employee can be tagged to only one department. So from employee side, it is one to one. however, one department can have multiple employees. So it is one to many from department side.

Comment: The fact that one employee can be tagged to only one department implies a *to-one* association, but not necessarily a *one-to-one*. Since one department can have multiple employees, `Employee.dept` should be marked many-to-one

Comment: I got your point.. @crizzis.. thanks for pointing this out to me..  In above scenario, the best suited option would be ManyToOne. Is it necessary that if one side entity is showing oneTomany, other side should show manyToOne ? same goes with oneToOne ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you may run into trouble

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @crizzis